# Sidekiq on AWS ElasticBeantaslk not connecting to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, sidekiq

Im having trouble launching Sidekiq on my AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment.

I am running Sidekiq 4.1.0 with my Rails application.

I logged directly into the EC2 instance to start Sidekiq manually and when I run this:

`bundle exec sidekiq -e staging -q default -q mailers`

I get this error from the Insance:

`2016-02-10T07:19:34.172Z 1655 TID-gn7dktok8 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.1.0 with redis options {:url=>"redis://xxxx.amazonaws.com:6379"}
'xxxx.xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production", "staging"]`

I checked the RDS database URL its trying to connect to and its the right one for the environment I am trying to run this on.

My sidekiq config file looks like this:

```
redis_url = ENV['REDIS_URL']

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
   config.redis = { url: redis_url, namespace: "swimlanes_#{Rails.env}" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
   config.redis = { url: redis_url, namespace: "swimlanes_#{Rails.env}" }
end
```

I have tried everything. Do you know what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like I helped you find the issue on GitHub: setting the Rails env incorrectly somewhere?

Comment: For anyone else experiencing this with multiple environments using ELB please refer to this issue: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2829